# How to add a "type here" message to a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

If the text box has no keyboard focus and no text, then show italic gray "type here" text "inside" it. How? What doesn't work:

- Setting the `Text` property - it messes up data binding.
- Overriding the template - it's messy and overridden already anyway.

Preferably, I'd like the solution to be as much XAML and as little C# as possible. Perhaps I could create an attached property that would do some magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as a **Watermark**.  I'm unfamiliar with WPF, but searching [WPF & Watermark](http://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+watermarkedtextbox) on "the google" returns a ton of results.

Comment: +1 for your answer :). Watermarked text is very popular in WPF/Silverlight/whatnot and there are hundreds solutions out there...

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've seen till now, is *InfoTextBox* from Kevin's WPF [Bag-o-Tricks library](http://j832.com/bagotricks/). Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Create a style for your TextBox. It's one of the easiest ways to add a 'watermark' to your TextBox. The code creates a simple style and binds it to a TextBox.

(Code extracted from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d565c79e-6b4a-44e2-a566-a4a622eab22f/how-to-set-watermark-for-textbox-in-simple-way?forum=wpf)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyWaterMarkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">           
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="White" BorderBrush="#FF7D8683" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="WaterMarkLabel" Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" Foreground="Gray" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Text" Value=""/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="WaterMarkLabel" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DimGray"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyWaterMarkStyle}" Height="25" Tag="Water mark"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution, but you could always add a `TextBlock` overlaying the `TextBox` and change it's `Visible` property when the `TextBox` gains or loses focus.

Nasty hack, but somewhat innovative? Do I get brownie points for that? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Syncfusion for WPF.
It contains the SfTextBoxExt which supports watermark and other features.

[Look here](http://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/sftextboxext/overview)